# Why is the following simple assignment statement in python taking a lot of time to execute?

Tags: python, pandas

The below code snippet is taking too much time to execute. It only consist of a simple for loop and if loop. I'm pretty sure that it's not any performance issue as my system is powerful. Can someone let me know why and also any possible solution?

```
new_dict= {}
for cnt,xx in enumerate(data):
    w = som.winner(xx)

    if w not in cluster_centers.keys():
        new_dict[w]=count
        count+=1

    dataframe['Values'].iloc[cnt]= new_dict[w]
```

Comment: please provide data samples

Comment: Data is a 2D array that has 2 columns and more than 5000 rows. Doesn't matter the length of the row, one iteration is taking one full second anyways. I just need to know how to speed it up.

Comment: Good we have a couple of those lying around.

Comment: More seriously: there is a tool specially designed to find out performances bottlenecks, it's called a profiler, and there are a few available for Python: https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html - this will yield much better results than any crystal ball ;-)

Comment: Oh and yes (I was about to comment on this but Christian Sloper beat me): if `cluster_centers` is a dict, you already have a very easy fix - might not be the main bottleneck but it will definitly improve perfs (and resources usage).

Answer (score 1):

Without sample data it is hard to be sure.  We can't for sure know how much time "`som.winner`" takes, you would need to profile ( see [docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html](http://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) for an example ) the code for that.  I am going to guess that the most costly is the

"`w not in cluster_centers.keys()`" part of the loop.

```
new_dict= {}
for cnt,xx in enumerate(data):
    w = som.winner(xx)

    if w not in cluster_centers:
        new_dict[w]=count
        count+=1

    dataframe['Values'].iloc[cnt]= new_dict[w]
```

Note, I assume cluster_center is a dictionary. If it is an another arbitrary datastructure, i suggest creating a set for O(1) lookup.

That being said, this really looks like something that can be done without looping.  So if you can provide some same data for `data`and `dataframe`, we can probably help you out.

Comment: time for a coffee break ?-)

Comment: yes, I am actually going to the machine right now hehe :-)

Comment: You may want to add a note about profilers when you're back then so your answer is as complete as possible ;-)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution Found!!**

I had tried all the below answers that all of you had mentioned. But still it wasn't drastically improving anything. But upon a little more research, I found out the exact reason why this is happening.

```
dataframe['Values'].iloc[cnt]= new_dict[w]
```

This statement should be changed to:

```
dataframe['Values'].at[cnt]= new_dict[w]
```

After implementing this, I was able to get it run in less than 5sec whereas in the other case, it was taking nearly half an hour. Thanks Everybody!